# An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Users' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to make my SQL Server database work with my aspx project. I have created a table for Users who reads data from my webform text fields. However, for whatever reason it tries to assign my `Users` table `id` column to the 1st textbox in my web project. I cannot seem to think of a way to fix it. Could you help me?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Username] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [Password] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [Email] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
```

and here I assign the values from webform:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "','u')", con);
```

The webform markup:

```
        <div class="center-page">
            <label class="col-xs-11">Username</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbUname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">Password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbPass" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbCPass" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Name"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>

            <label class="col-xs-11">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col-xs-11 space-vert">
                <asp:Button ID="btSignup" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="btSignup_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: In your insert statement you need to supply the list of columns.  Insert into users (username, password, ....) values(..)

Comment: Also: **do not** just simply make each column of your table a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` because you're too lazy to think about the proper sizing - **invest that time** and make sure you use proper datatypes and lengths!

Comment: As already stated this is incredibly scary code because it is wide open to sql injection. But the error occurs because you have an extra value 'u' at the end of your insert statement. What is that for?

Comment: And passwords should NEVER be stored in plain text. Always hash and salt your passwords and store the encrypted value.

Comment: What has me wondering here is that your table definition posted does not have an identity so the error you reported cannot come from the insert statement you posted.

Comment: thank you @SeanLange i am aware of sqlinjections, this project is purely for my own training and understanding of how data connections work.

Comment: Then I would suggest that for your own training you properly parameterize your queries. It is not just good practice, it is crucial in an application.

Comment: Okay i will do it after i get to work this one. right now i have changed the command to the following:

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users ( Username, Password, Email, Name) values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "')", con);

it says that i leave id as a null however id is auto-incremented. Where is the problem here?

Comment: The table definition you posted here is NOT an identity so it would require you to enter a value.

Answer (score 2):

You just simply need to **explicitly** specify the columns you want to *insert into* in your `INSERT` command - something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users(Username, Password, Email, Name)
VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4);
```

Comment: I see, thank you. 
thought this would work. 
But for whatever reason it says that it wants to add nulls to id field

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users(Username, Password, Email, Name) values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "')", con);

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@tbUname". I do not understand why it thinks i want to set id to a varchar

Comment: @janekjan it is difficult to help when you only post snippets of code and partial DDL (which is not consistent with the reported error). If you want help, you need to put more effort into providing information. In addition, learn to debug your code. You generate a sql statement via code - to debug it you need to actually **see** it (and post it) so others can understand what your code is doing and compare it with what you claim to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

is your ID fiels is identity field with auto increment?
i think its not because i don't see you use

```
IDENTITY(1,1)
```

in your create table, then you need to use it in your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users(Id,Username, Password, Email, Name)
VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4,@val5);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue:
Replace this query...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "','u')", con);

with this one down here

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ( [Username], [Password], [Email],[Name])VALUES('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "')", con);